# Flutter Shared Preferences are not initializing in tests

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, testing, sharedpreferences

I am trying to write a test to check my ThreadService. It uses prefs and works okay in the app, but when I run a test I get a `LateInitializationError: Field prefs has not been initialized.` Here is the code of the test:

```
late SharedPreferences prefs;
void main() async {
  setUp(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({
        (...)
    });
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  });
  test('test', () async {
    final threadService = ThreadService(boardTag: 'pr', threadId: 1008826);

    await threadService.getRoots();
    (...)
  });
}
```

I have tried to move `prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();` in test body, but it did not work.

Comment: I solved it. The error happens not in the test file, but in ThreadService class. You need to initialize prefs `prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();` in the class you use, because if you do in test file, it is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  test('test SharedPreferences instance created', () async {
    final Map<String, Object> values = <String, Object>{'token': 'value'};
    SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues(values);

    expect(await SharedPreferences.getInstance(), isA<SharedPreferences>());
  });
}
```